# "-moz-","-webkit-","-o-","-ms-"

Tags: jquery, html

I am using an existing jQuery code, which includes an array of browser prefixes :

```
"-moz-", "-webkit-", "-o-", "-ms-"
```

The code isn't working for Google Chrome.
Is there a prefix for Google Chrome included in this array ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: -webkit = safari and chrome. But whats your actual probelm ?

Comment: but jquery is related to -webkit.What are you talking about?

Comment: i have copied a jquery code from someplace , this code is working fine on all browsers exept google chrome , so i thought it is not mentioned in this array (this array is used in the code)

Comment: what IS your actual question? Post some more code ... which routine is not working? What exactly do you want to achive? .... Am I really spending time on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not **jQuery** code but **CSS** prefix

> -moz- Firefox, 
>   -webkit- Safari and Chrome
>   -o- for Opera
>   -ms- for Internet Explorer

Comment: i'm very curious to see the routine he is talking about ...

Comment: check this  http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/

Comment: This plugin actually work on Chrome.