# What are -webkit- , -moz- , -o- on background attributes in css?

Tags: css

I don't know what these are in css.

```
-webkit-background-size   
-moz-background-size     
-o-background-size
```

Please help me.

Comment: Refer it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12212154/2198378

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-webkit-, -moz- and -o- are browser specific versions of common css attributes for Webkit, Mozilla and Opera respectively. There is also -ie- for IE.

Oftentimes they are needed to make newer CSS features available in these browsers, before they themselves have enabled full support. Eventually though, the newer versions of the browsers do not need them.

Look [here](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients) for a list of what browsers need these tags in order to render gradients. There are similar tables for the background attributes, but I am unaware from the top of my head of ones that use all of the aforementioned browser specifics. But I assume you yourself would know of one?

Comment: you mean these are for showing a background good in others browseres ??

Comment: I updated my answer somewhat. Yes, they are for getting certain css properties to display in browsers that are otherwise too old to support them.

Answer (score 0):

They are vendor specific CSS. See here for more info  [VENDOR SPECIFIC](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vendorspecific)

and also check this out : [CAN I USE](http://caniuse.com/) . this is to know the supported CSS or JS functionalities. :)

happy coding!